# Does AJAX call reload my entire page in Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to do an AJAX call from my Razor Pages page.

#### JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '?handler=Delete',
    data: {
        id: $(this).data('id')
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        // Required for POST, but have same issue if I removed this
        // and use GET
        xhr.setRequestHeader('XSRF-TOKEN',
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
})
.fail(function (e) {
    alert(e.responseText);
})
.always(function () {
    // Removed to simplify issue
    //location.reload(true);
});
```

#### Code behind:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnPostDeleteAsync(int id)
{
    string userId = UserManager.GetUserId(User);
    var area = DbContext.Areas.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserId == userId && a.Id == id);
    if (area != null)
    {
        DbContext.Remove(area);
        await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

And, in fact, this works correctly and the item is deleted.

However, the `$.ajax.fail()` handler is called and the error indicates there was a `NullReferenceException`.

[image: AJAX Error]

The exception is raised in my markup (CSHTML file):

```
@if (Model.ActiveAreas.Count == 0)  @***** NullReferenceException here! *****@
{
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        You don't have any active life areas.
    </div>
}
```

The reason there is this exception is because all of the properties of my page model are null. They are null because my `OnGetAsync()` method is never called to initialize them!

My question is why is my markup executing as though I'm updating the entire page? I'm doing an AJAX call. I don't want to update the entire page. So I don't know why my `OnGetAsync()` would ever need to be called.

Comment: Isn't your page reloading when the ajax call completes? Because of the `location.reload(true)` in the `always` callback?

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson: The error is shows in my `fail()` handler. I believe that is called before I refresh the page. Also, reloading the page should work fine. At least, it does when I go to the page initially.

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson: And I've just confirmed in the Chrome debugger that `fail()` runs before `(always)`.

Comment: 'Model.ActiveAreas' is null, find out why, that doesn't show in the code you have provided.

Comment: I know why. Because my `OnGet()` handler initializes the model and it's never called in this case. But why should it need to be called? I'm not refreshing the entire page. I'm making an AJAX call.

Comment: The stack trace in you image clearly states where has the exception occurred. If you would post that code as well, it would be much easier to assist you.

Comment: @gpro: I have posted the lines where the exception occurs. But I already know why it's null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> (Based on your provided code)

**I think problem in your a `always()` callback function or the `Cliek` event or your return statement.**

**always():**

The callback function passed to the `always()` function is called whenever the AJAX request finishes, regardless of whether or not the AJAX request succeeds or fails. The three parameters passed to the callback function will be either the same three parameters passed to `done()` or `fail()`, depending on whether the AJAX request succeeds or fails.

In response to a successful request, the function's arguments are the same as those of `.done(): data, textStatus, and the jqXHR object`. For failed requests the arguments are the same as those of `.fail(): the jqXHR object, textStatus, and errorThrown`.

The `deferred.always()` method receives the arguments that were used to `.resolve()` or `.reject()` the Deferred object, which are often very different. For this reason, it's best to use it only for actions that do not require inspecting the arguments. In all other cases, use explicit `.done()` or `.fail()` handlers since the arguments will have well-known orders.

Reference:

1. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jquery/ajax.html
2. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
3. https://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/

**OR**

**Cliek event:**  I think your button is triggering a page refresh. so use `preventDefault()` in your click event.

Example:

```
$('...').on('click', function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();//add the prevent default.

    //Your code

});
```

**OR**

**Return Statement:** If your `OnPostDelete` method return `Page()` the please change it to `JsonResult` or `RedirectToPage`.

Example:

```
   public Task<IActionResult> OnPostDelete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            //Your Code

           return Page();//Remove it

           return new JsonResult ("Customer Deleted Successfully!");// Use some thing like it as u need.

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");//if u want to reload page then use it.
        }
```

Comment: @JonathanWood always() function is called whenever the AJAX request finishes, regardless of whether or not the AJAX request succeeds or fails

Comment: The error in my issue is being displayed from the `fail()` handler. This happens *before* the `always()` handler has been called. Therefore, the issue cannot be due to `always()` behavior. This is all aside from the fact that I cannot see how `always()` could *ever* cause the issue I'm seeing.

Comment: @JonathanWood I think your button is triggering a page refresh. so use `preventDefault()` in your click event. see my update answer.

Comment: The element is `<img src="/images/Delete.png" class="delete-area button-img" data-id="8" title="Delete">`. Anyway, I tried adding `preventDefault()` but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Using `JsonResult` does in fact stop the error! Since this is an AJAX call, I would never want to return a page. But if I return `new JsonResult("Here I am!");`, then the `fail()` handler is NOT called. So that's a big help. Although I still don't understand why.

Comment: @JonathanWood Because "The `OnPostDelete` handler method calls the Page helper method. Page returns an instance of `PageResult`. Returning Page is similar to how actions in controllers return View. `PageResult` is the default return type for a handler method. A handler method that returns void renders the page." https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/action-results

Comment: I don't see where my OnPostDelete() handler calls the Page helper method.